# Is there a way to show X equal or smaller than Y?

Tags: factorial

**X**=$1!+2!+3!+...+n!$

**Y**=$n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+....+n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-a)$

Is there a way to show X equal or smaller than Y?

for $a= n-1$ and and $a=n-2$

i found that

Y=$n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)(n-2)+..+n!+n!$

However after this point do not find a logical connection and do not have idea about solving this problem.

Comment: What the possible values of $a$?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  For $a=n-1$ each term of $Y$ is at least as large as the corresponding term of $X$ ($n>1!,n(n-1)>2!$ and so on)  so clearly $Y>X$ in this case.  But the statement is clearly not true for small $a$...so what are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Without additional hypotheses (e.g., some lower limit on $a$) the statement is false in general. For example, if $n=4$ and $a=1$ then $X=31$ but $Y=16.$

Comment: sorry for forgotten the additional info. $n=1,3,4,5,.. x$ and $a=1,3,4,5,.. x$

Comment: That is not very helpful for two reasons: (1) the double dot seems to suggest some logical progression but why is 2 excluded and what does $x$ mean? (2) my counterexample $n=4,\ a=1$ is included in the values that you enumerate.